# Один скрипт для перезапуска нескольких сцен

Tags: unity3d

Существует 5 сцен в редакторе юнити. Когда уровень проходится, запускается сцена "следующий уровень", на которой висит button, при нажатии на которую требуется перейти на следующий уровень. То есть был уровень с первой сцены, после прохождения нужно перейти, соответственно на второй, и так далее.

Я реализую это так. Для каждого уровня создаю дополнительную сцену - "следующий уровень", на которой висит кнопка, с отдельным для каждой сцены скриптом.
Вариант, конечно, работает. Но, мне кажется, оптимизация оставляет желать лучшего.

Вообщем, вопрос, можно ли сделать это все в одной сцене - "следующий уровень", в одном скрипте?

Answer (score 0):

Каждая сцена-уровень имеет свой индекс. Вы можете переключаться между ним используя индексы сцен. 
После прохождения уровня вы увеличиваете индекс на один и загружаете свою сцену с кнопкой. Которая вызовет новый уровень.В итоге у вас там 5 сцен уровней и 1 сцена переключения.